# Why study the log of the absolute value of the error induced by a numerical method when solving a PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Often when validating the use of a numerical PDE solution method, one considers the log of the absolute value of the error. In particular, instead of simply looking at the difference between the exact solution and the numerical method, one plots the log of the absolute value of the error. Why is this useful? How does one interpret the log of the absolute value of the error?